# Uploading local artifact into raw repository

Tags: groovy, nexus3

Hello thanks for the script and demo it is very useful. Is there any documentation or a groovy script for uploading local artifcats into a hosted raw repository ?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for doing this is available here: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/raw.html#_uploading_files_to_hosted_raw_repositories